# Remove records from mutable.mutableList in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a mutable.MutableList[emp] with following structure.

```
case class emp(name: String,id:String,sal: Long,dept: String)
```

I am generating records based on above case class in the below mutable.MutableList[emp].

```
val list1: mutable.MutableList[emp]  = ((mike, 1, 123, HR),(mike,2,123,sys),(Lind,1,2323,sys))
```

If I have same name with id 1 and 2, I need to take only 2 and drop id 1 record. Id id 2 is not present, I have to take id 1.

How do achieve this? I tried it with following way but results are not accurate:

```
0. converted mutable.mutableList to Dataframe
1. filtered records with id 1(id1s_DF)
2. filtered records with id 2(other_rec_DF)
3. joined records with name and used leftsemi as join condition.
val join_info_DF = other_rec_DF.join(id1s_DF, id1s_DF("name") =!= other_rec_DF("name"),"leftsemi")
```

Above join will give all the names which are present in other_rec_DS and not present in Other_rec_DF.

Looks like I am doing some thing wrong with the join and not getting expected results.

Could some please help me to achieve this in either mutableList or by converting it into Dataframe.

Thanks,
Babu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the size of your data is small enough you don't need something like Apache Spark to do the above task.

Doing this in plain scala code, the code would look something like below

```scala
case class Emp(name: String,id:Int,sal: Long,dept: String)

val list1: mutable.MutableList[Emp] = mutable.MutableList(
  Emp("mike", 1, 123, "HR"),
  Emp("mike", 2, 123, "sys"),
  Emp("Lind", 1, 2323, "sys")
)

val result = list1
  .groupBy(_.name)
  .mapValues(_.sortBy(_.id)(Ordering[Int].reverse).head)
  .values
result.foreach(println)
```

The output of the above code would be

```
Emp(Lind,1,2323,sys)
Emp(mike,2,123,sys)
```

The idea / approach is to make sure we group by the key on which you want to de-duplicate the items, sort them and pick the one with the highest id. We then drop the key and store only the values.

The above approach would work exactly the same way on Spark as well.

Comment: Thanks Ashwanth Kumar for your quick reply. We will get millions of records and also we need to consider if id2 is not present, we need to take id1. So this approach will work?

Comment: Yes sorting and picking the highest ID will work for 1 or many records in the group.